# IMPORTXML query returning redundant data in several cells

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets to get a price from a website.
The query is very straight forward and I manage to get the data I want.
However this data will appear in the cell where I wrote the query (which is ok) AND as well in the cell directly below, which prevent me from using a dynamic query with a parameter.

I tried the two following lines of code that have the same effect:

```
=IMPORTXML(TO_TEXT($A$1)&TO_TEXT(B3)&"/", "//div[@class='PriceHistoryStats--value']")

=IMPORTXML(TO_TEXT($A$1)&TO_TEXT(B3)&"/", "//*[@class='PriceHistoryStats--value']")
```

Where A1 is the general URL of the website:

https://opensea.io/assets/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/

and the column B contains the parameter of the asset from which I am trying to retrieve the price.
Currently the line of code is in cell C3.
I get a result "Ξ0" returned in both C3 and C4.
I need this result to be returned only in C3.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the url as well as the expected output.

Comment: This is done, let me know if you need more information!

Comment: I get a "page not found" error with that url.

Comment: the full URL with the parameter "TO_TEXT(B3)" is https://opensea.io/assets/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/0000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way - where `$A$1` is the url in your last comment:

```
=IMPORTXML($A$1, "//div[@class='item--large']//div[@class='PriceHistoryStats--stat']/div[@class='PriceHistoryStats--value']/text()")
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for looking at it! I still have the problem but found a workaround by passing the IMPORT XML() in argument to the function UNIQUE(), that solved it.

Comment: @AkaiSedo It only solves the problem in this particular case, because the two items are equal. In other cases, they may have different values, in which case `unique()` won't solve it, and you'll have to select one of the two sources as the target.

Comment: You are right. My work around only works because the webpages I am parsing are structured in this particular way. However I moved to scripting because importxml is limited to 50 query per worksheet. Thank you very much for your help!